# how to get multiple rows using select?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to track all the changes that happened on my table

I tried this query

```
Update Stocks
Set stockOut = 100
,TrackDate = '1/30/2016'
 ,stockOnHand = stockOnHand - 400
 WHERE itemID = '4589-S';
```

and this one.Both on Different date.

```
    Update Stocks
Set stockOut = 200
,TrackDate = '2/30/2016'
 ,stockOnHand = stockOnHand - 400
 WHERE itemID = '4589-S';
```

Now I used this query

```
SELECT
[ItemID]
      ,[ProdID]
      ,[stockOnHand]
      ,[stockIn]
      ,[stockOut]
      ,[TrackDate]
 from Stocks
where TrackDate between '1/30/2016' and '5/30/2016'
```

to track the changes within the specific span of 
date.But I'm only getting **1** result only

I was Expecting to get 2 results because I've Updated this table in two different dates.

Comment: is it mysql  ? if mysql then I don't see date.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty pardon?

Comment: You tagged the question with `mysql` and the date format you are saving is not correct date.

Comment: if itemID is a PK, then you only have one row for this item so both updates worked with the same row and this is why you get only this row in your select

Comment: I was hoping to get multiple results of changes that happen between that span of time.How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two tables,

STOCK & STOCK_HISTORY

When inserting/updating stocks, you should also create a new record in the STOCK_HISTORY table. The columns of this table should be something like ID, STOCK_ID, ACTION (create, update, delete) and a TIMESTAMP.

This way, you have no useless info in the STOCK table, and whenever you want to list all changes of a stock you do:

```html
SELECT * FROM stocks s
  JOIN stock_history sh ON sh.stockId = s.id
  WHERE s.id = $stockId
```

Comment: So the **stock history** is like a mirror?I'm kinda getting the idea now.

Comment: Nope. Stock data is in the STOCK table, data related to stock changes is in the stock_history table. It's diferent data they handle

Comment: so the stockHistory should contain stockID,Update(TimeStamp),stock in,stock out,and stock in hand?

Comment: For performance reasons, I would just have: 
ID | STOCKID | UPDATE(timestamp) | ACTION(create, update, delete) | quantity (can be positive or negative)

Comment: So I'm using TimeStamp to generate reports or archivie the date of changes,also timestamp can give me multiple results?

Comment: Well, depends what you mean from multiple results.
The query I posted in the answer would return all history changes for a given STOCK along with the stock data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113340/discussion-between-rai-nalasa-and-borjante).

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE queries change existing rows.

INSERT queries add new rows.

Both your update queries changed the same row.

Comment: But he is right, only 1 row updated, so only 1 row can be on the output. Once it updated, the old version no longer exists.

Comment: @sagi what query could I use that I can view the old versions as well?like see the reports of what happen during specific time span?

Comment: Don't update them, insert them as new row with different date @rainalasa

Comment: will that retain the primary key ID the same?

Comment: You will neeed an extra table to track changes

Comment: @Borjante can you give me clue how?

Answer (score 0):

> To archive every change made to your table, add a **TRIGGER**.
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

The trigger will archive the full row or parts of it by writing it to another table in case the row gets deletet or updated. You will have to define inside the TRIGGER-Definition what exactly happens when a row is changed and which values of the row should be archived.